# I want to send a large json object through a POST request

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am using a the fetch api to send a post request to my NodeJS/Express/MongoDB based API but somehow, only some of the fields are posted to the MongoDB collection. The rest are omitted. When I use console.log to print the whole js object in the console, I get a partial object with a ... at the end, which when hovered over, shows "Value below was evaluated just now". Looks like the request is sending the object in chunks. I want to send the whole object. How can I send the whole object?

**FRONTEND:**

```
document.getElementById('contact-submit').onclick = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

      console.log(postData('http://localhost:4001/people',{
            

                "name":document.getElementById('name').value.toString(),
                "age": document.getElementById('age').value ,
                "sex":document.getElementById('sex').value,
                "address":document.getElementById('address').value,
                "class": document.getElementById('class').value,
                "degree": Number(document.getElementById('degree').value),
                "grade":document.getElementById('grade').value,
                "notes":Date(document.getElementById('notes').value),
                "resume":Number(document.getElementById('resume').value),
                "skills":criteria,
                "rounds":rounds,
                
            
          }));
    }



    async function postData(url = '', data ={}){


        console.log(data);

        const response = await fetch(url, {

            

            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return response.json();
    }
```

The object comes from a form, and only a part of it gets posted in the api.
PS. The API on its own works fine and POSTs complete objects when operated on through postman.

Comment: You're **already** sending the whole object. *"When I use console.log to print the whole js object in the console, I get a partial object with a ... at the end, which when hovered over, shows "Value below was evaluated just now"."* That's **purely** a console thing. It has nothing whatsoever to do with what's sent by `fetch`.

Comment: Did you try to _click_ the ellipsis? `console.log` doesn't show the whole object when it's big, but allows you to unfold the complete list of fields and their contents.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at "body: JSON.stringify(data)" line and see if data is received entirely.

Comment: Yes, clicking the ellipsis shows the whole object, but only a chunk of the object is sent to the Database collection.